# Javascript: Some kind of preg_match with a callback on each match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to implement a dynamic service in Angular (though Angular isn't really that big a factor), and I can't figure out how to implement the following hypothetical.

Let's say I have a regex pattern,

```
// Should match a phone number
/^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/
```

and I want a method that will take a given string, which is likely to be a paragraph of text, find all the strings matching the pattern, and run a method on them to replace the phone numbers with the contacts they belong to in an address book.

```
var string = "555-790-2342 is one, 555-555-2344 is another.";
```

I can pattern.test to see if anything matches, and I could do a search and replace, but if, for example, the search and replace isn't a one-to-one, what would the process be?  Assume there's a list of results, like:

```
var numbers = {
    "555-790-2342" : "John Smith", 
    "555-555-2344" : "Bob Smith", 
    "555-324-2342" : "Dana Smith"
};
```

I want each pattern matched to hit the numbers object and replace the matched number(key) with the appropriate name(value) from the numbers object.  I have absolutely no idea how this might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A surprisingly little-known feature:

```
string.replace(/your regex here/g,function(match,sub1,sub2) {
    // for obvious reasons, use meaningful argument names!
    // now do stuff
    // optionally:
    return match;
});
```

At face value the whole thing is a no-op, as not only does it just return the unmodified match as the replacement, but it also discards the resulting string anyway (because it's not assigned to a variable). But that callback can have side-effects, such as populating an object, etc.

Of course, if you want, you can `return` other things too, such as `return numbers[match];`

Comment: That works absolutely perfectly, and I am genuinely dazzled at the speed of your response.  Danke.